# Determining if a number evenly divides by 25, Python

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to check if each number in a list is evenly divisible by 25 using Python. I'm not sure what is the right process. I want to do something like this:

```
n = [100, 101, 102, 125, 355, 275, 435, 134, 78, 550]
for row in rows:

    if n / 25 == an evenly divisble number:
        row.STATUS = "Major"
    else:
        row.STATUS = "Minor"
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is `n` meant to be a list, as shown, or an integer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [the modulo operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

```
for row in rows:
    if n % 25:
        row.STATUS = "Minor"
    else:
        row.STATUS = "Major"
```

or

```
for row in rows:
    row.STATUS = "Minor" if n % 25 else "Major"
```

`n % 25` means "Give me the remainder when `n` is divided by `25`".

Since `0` is `False`y, you don't need to explicitly compare to `0`, just use it directly in the `if` -- if the remainder is `0`, then it's a major row. If it's not, it's a minor row.

Comment: I've always found this syntax confusing. `if n % 25:` reads like "if n *is* divisible by 25" rather than the other way around. But that's just me.

Comment: @NullUserException That's why I explained it :) Just get used to reading it as "If n _has a remainder_ when divided by 25".

Comment: Thanks a lot agf! You're quick on the response. It's much appreciated. You gave me exactly what iw as looking for! Cheers.

Answer (score 18):

Use the modulo operator to determine the division remainder:

```
if n % 25 == 0:
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Sven!