# It seems my code skips a part for no clear reason

Tags: python

I wrote the code below to print out multiples of 3 and 5 in a range of numbers from 1 - 100 but it seems that I only keep on getting the multiples of 3 only.

```
counter = 1
for i in range(1, 101):
    if 3 * counter == i:
        print(i)
        counter += 1
    elif 5 * counter == i:
        print(i)
        counter += 1
```

Can someone help me figure out the issue.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why are you comparing against `counter` at all? Shouldn't you just be looking at `i`? Are you maybe looking for [`if i % 3 == 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10018937/354577)?

Comment: I'm trying to print out the multiples of 3 and 5. I used the counter so I would be able to check if the current number from the range... is equal to 3 or 5 x counter.

Comment: What about using `i % 3` and `i % 5`?

Comment: So why does the `counter` matter? `i` takes on the values 1 to 100. You just need to see if it divides evenly by 3 and / or 5. (Think about what `counter` is counting: the _number_ of values that divide by 3 or 5.)

Comment: When `i==3`, the counter will be increased to 2, when `i==6`, counter will be increased to 3, and so on. The counter may never be lower than a third of `i`, therefore it will never be a fifth of `i`.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you to run your code line by line in a debugger such as the [Python visualizer](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) and observe what's happening to your variables and conditions. It will become a lot clearer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at what happens as this executes.

```
counter = 1
i = 1
3 * counter = 3
5 * counter = 5

counter = 1
i = 2
3 * counter = 3
5 * counter = 5

counter = 1
i = 3
3 * counter = 3
printed: 3
counter += 1

counter = 2
i = 4
3 * counter = 6
5 * counter = 10

counter = 2
i = 5
3 * counter = 6
5 * counter = 10

counter = 2
i = 6
3 * counter = 6
printed: 6
counter += 1
```

If you want all multiples of 3 and 5, you want to use the modulo operator (`%`).

```
count = 0

for i in range(1, 101):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        print(i)
        count += 1

print(f"counted: {count}")
```

Comment: That's the best answer, the OP really needed to see his code working. +1

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
for i in range(1, 101):
    if (0 in [i%3, i%5]):
        print(i)
```

---

The `%` operator is called the **modulo operator**, and returns the remainder of the given division.

```
>>> 4 % 2
0
>>> 4 % 3
1
>>> 3 % 4
3
```

In your case, since you are searching for numbers that are multiples of 3 **or** 5, this operator is what you need.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware that I was reverting your edits when editing my answer. Thanks for telling me this rule.

Answer (score 0):

You are solving Project Euler #1?
Since this is the first question I will help, but in general posting the entire question will ruin the fun, if you are stuck post the specific part you need help on.

You do not want to test your counter, since you are basically keeping track of what 3 (the smallest value) should be divided by to get that number.

```
counter = 1

for i in range(1, 101):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(i)
        counter += 1
    if i % 5 == 0:
        print(i)
        counter += 1

print(f"counted: {counter}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I never thought of solving it this way

Answer (score 0):

Your program can not work. When i==3, the counter will be increased to 2, when i==6, counter will be increased to 3, and so on. The counter may never be lower than a third of i, therefore it will never be a fifth of i.

So, if you want to stick with the idea of the counter, you need two counters. One for fifths, the other for thirds:

```
counter3 = 1
counter5 = 1
for i in range(1, 101):
    if (3 * counter3) == i:
        print(i)
        counter3 += 1
    if 5 * counter5 == i:
        print(i)
        counter5 += 1
```

But there are much more elegant ways to find numbers divisible by 3 and 5.

Comment: Please note that numbers that are divisable by both 3 and 5 will be printed twice here.